# Parsing problems HTML -> PDF using iText

Tags: html, css, vb.net, pdf, itext

Have a problem converting html to PDF using iText. I have code:

```
Dim currentContext As String = 
   HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ejik.pdf")
Dim pdfDoc As New Document()
pdfDoc = New Document(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F)
Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New 
   FileStream(currentContext, FileMode.CreateNew))
pdfDoc.Open()
Dim sr
sr = New StringReader("<p style='position:absolute; left:100; top:400; 
   color:red'>Hello, world!</p>")
XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr)
pdfDoc.Close()
```

I got the PDF file where the "Hello, world" is not positioned properly. It looks like iText does not recognizes `"position:absolute; left:100; top:400;"`. Could you give me any idea, please? Thank you for any answer!

Comment: Can you reproduce it in the most recent version of iText, 7.1.0, with the pdfHTML add-on?

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse than you, it works it version 7!